# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes', keras

Tags: keras

I haven't applied any statement from TensorFlow, which means I adopted the layer API from Keras. But the error occurred from the statement
"model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)".

I have no idea about that.

Could Someone help me?

The shape of Input in my task is (batch_size, 8, 224, 224, 3). I hope to use the pre-trained mobilenet. But the weights of the pre-trained model are special for the input which has 3 channels. So I divide the input of my task into 8 parts whose shape is (batch_size, 1, 224, 224, 3). Then I reshape each part to the shape batch_size, 224, 224, 3.

```
import sys

from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import (Activation, Add, Concatenate, Conv2D,
                          DepthwiseConv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D,
                          ZeroPadding2D, Reshape)
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
import keras


def _depthwise_conv_block(inputs, pointwise_conv_filters, alpha,
                          depth_multiplier=1, strides=(1, 1), block_id=1):
    pointwise_conv_filters = int(pointwise_conv_filters * alpha)
  
    x = DepthwiseConv2D((3, 3),
                        padding='same',
                        depth_multiplier=depth_multiplier,
                        strides=strides,
                        use_bias=False)(inputs)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(relu6)(x)

   
    x = Conv2D(pointwise_conv_filters, (1, 1),
               padding='same',
               use_bias=False,
               strides=(1, 1))(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    return Activation(relu6)(x)


def _conv_block(inputs, filters, alpha, kernel=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1)):
    filters = int(filters * alpha)
    x = Conv2D(filters, kernel,
               padding='same',
               use_bias=False,
               strides=strides)(inputs)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    return Activation(relu6)(x)


def relu6(x):
    return K.relu(x, max_value=6)


def clipped_mobilenetV1():
    base_model = keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), alpha=1.0, depth_multiplier=1,
                                                        dropout=1e-3,
                                                        include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None,
                                                        pooling=None,
                                                        classes=1000, )

    return Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer("conv_pw_4_relu").output)



def pretrained_mobilenetV1_2(se_maps):
    x = list()
    c_mobilenetV1 = clipped_mobilenetV1()
    for i in range(0, 8):
        x_ = Reshape((224, 224, 3))(se_maps[:, i, :, :, :])
        x_ = c_mobilenetV1(x_)
        x.append(x_)
    x = Concatenate(axis=-1)(x)

    x = _depthwise_conv_block(x, 1, alpha=1, depth_multiplier=1,
                              strides=(2, 2), block_id=4)

    return x


if __name__ == "__main__":


    inputs = Input([8, 224, 224, 3])
    x = pretrained_mobilenetV1_2(inputs)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

    model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

```
def pretrained_mobilenetV1_2(se_maps, args):

    x = TimeDistributed(clipped_mobilenetV1())(se_maps)
    x = Reshape((28, 28, 8 * 256))(x)
    x = _depthwise_conv_block(x, args.lstm, alpha=1, depth_multiplier=1,
                              strides=(2, 2), block_id=4)

    return x
```

The API Timedistrubuted() can confront the situation.